# How do I "clean up" a machine after using the local provider?

Tags: juju, lxc

I'm doing some testing and sometimes I have issues with containers and juju. How do I clean up a machine so that I can start using the local provider "from scratch" without reinstalling?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

LXC containers and the Juju environment need to persist through a reboot, so everything is not contained in one place.

First, ensure that you have the environment destroyed and the containers are not running. Then remove the following files and directories:

```
/etc/init/juju-* 
/etc/lxc/auto/juju-*
/etc/rsyslog.d/25-juju* 
/var/lib/juju/containers/* 
/var/lib/lxc/juju-* 
~/.juju/<env> 
~/.juju/environments/<env>.jenv
```

Then you can reboostrap with a clean environment.

In certain cases you might need to list, stop, and destroy containers by hand, do this before removing the Juju files.

- http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/lxc-ls.1.html
- http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/lxc-stop.1.html
- http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/lxc-destroy.1.html

Comment: This 2 command didn't work for me: `sudo rm -r /etc/lxc/auto/juju-*` AND `sudo rm -r /var/lib/lxc/juju-*`

Answer (score 1):

You might find the following snippet I use helpful:

http://blog.naydenov.net/2014/03/remove-juju-local-environment-cleanly/

It's a bash script that needs to be run as root, and it tries to clean up aggressively all remnants of a local juju environment, including LXC templates, containers, logs, running mongodb test servers, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can use `sudo /sbin/remove-juju-services` command, which should exist if the machines were provisioned manually at some point, or if it doesn't, what is does is:

```
for path_to_unit in $(ls /etc/systemd/system/juju*); do
  echo "removing juju service: $path_to_unit"
  unit=$(basename "$path_to_unit")
  systemctl stop "$unit"
  systemctl disable "$unit"
  systemctl daemon-reload
  rm -f "$path_to_unit"
done

echo "removing /var/lib/juju/tools/*"
rm -rf /var/lib/juju/tools/*

echo "removing /var/lib/juju/db/*"
rm -rf /var/lib/juju/db/*

echo "removing /var/lib/juju/raft/*"
rm -rf /var/lib/juju/raft/*

echo "removing /var/run/juju/*"
rm -rf /var/run/juju/*

has_juju_db_snap=$(snap info juju-db | grep installed:)
if [ ! -z "$has_juju_db_snap" ]; then
  echo "removing juju-db snap and any persisted database data"
  snap remove --purge juju-db
fi
```