# How can I downgrade my juju revision?

Tags: juju

I installed the latest juju development release -  and due to some bugs, I would like to revert back to stable, how do I do that?

I've executed the following against my machine:

```
sudo apt-get remove juju juju-local
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/juju-devel.list
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:juju/stable
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install juju juju-local
```

It still shows the juju development version as installed. What went wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Juju is a meta package. You also need to remove juju-core

```
sudo apt-get remove juju-core
```

and this will remove the development binaries for juju devel from your machine, now after removing the devel ppa, and wiping any of the [leftovers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/403618/how-do-i-clean-up-a-machine-after-using-the-local-provider) you're free to install Stable again with:

```
sudo apt-get install juju juju-local
```